# create rows with specific values from another column after particular cells_python

Tags: python, pandas, row

I have a df like this

[image]

The goal is to create new rows in this format

[image]

Is there any way of doing this in python?

many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try with `stack` the `split` and `explode`

```
s = df.stack()
s = s.str.split(' ').explode()
```

Comment: thank you but it is not working and even so, it is not the format I'm looking for but, thx a lot for the suggestion